# hover on other element CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover

Why does the background-color of .a does not change when I hover? .b?

**CSS**

```
.a {
    color: red;
}

.b {
    color: orange;
}

.b:hover .a {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="a">AAAA
    <div class ="b">BBBB</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2NEgt/323/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 5):

Because `.a` is not descendent or comes after/inside of `.b`  which is condition to work for it

for example if you inverse it, since `.b` is descendent of `.a`, it will work

```
.a:hover .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select `.a` when it's a child of `.b` in a hover state. This could never happen `.a` is the parent of `.b`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to change background of parent on child hover this would not possible as it's parent of b if you change b's background color on hover of a then it will work

```
.a:hover .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

it's here
    http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/

Answer (score -2):

There is an error in your HTML also .a is not descendent

**HTML:**

`<div id="wrap">
    <div class="a">AAAA</div>
    <div class ="b">BBBB</div>
</div>`

**CSS:**

```
.a {
    color: red;
}
.b {
    color: orange;
}
.b:hover, .a:hover  {
  background-color: blue;
```

}

Comment: There is no html error. It may be not the nicest way to write the html, but its ok to do it this way.

Comment: @DerVampyr Because of the structure the CSS didn't work correctly in the fiddle link that he mentioned in the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: He don´t want both single elements blue. He want to hover a child element of ``.a`` (in this case `.b`) and therefore make ``.a`` blue